# SoundCloud Application Registration form is closed

Tags: soundcloud

I am trying to register a new app with SoundCloud. I therefore go to https://soundcloud.com/you/apps and click on "Sign up for a new app". This opens a google form that says:

> Due to the high amount of requests recently received, we will no longer be processing API application requests at this time. We are working to re-evaluate our process to make it more efficient.

The message is a little puzzling. I am not trying to use an API to register my app. I am trying to register it manually.

Anybody knows how to sign-up for a new app manually?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is customer service-related and not a programming question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said by sven-greinert in a comment, it is not possible anymore.

Answer (score 39):

You don't *have* to register an APP, even if you wanted to it would be quite hard to. The registration is closed for over a year now.
I had this problem too and managed to circumvent this by just grabbing my browsers client_id and working with that. Con: You can't access oauth features and personalized stuff, but you can query everything public on soundcloud and even download songs.

Just go on SoundCloud and open a track page, hit F12 and go to the Networking tab, then start the song and look out for requests containing a client_id.

It's is not really what you asked for but the only current way to work with their API.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to use oauth features like uploading a song.

Comment: @mabead Then it is basically impossible to do what you want currently. Wish they'd be opening the registration again.

Comment: Thanks for the browser client_id tip

Comment: Also, the API is pretty lackluster. The API is missing just simple stuff, in example your feed in the API for a reposted track will only show the original artist name but not who reposted it.

Comment: Good idea about client_id, however it doesn’t work for me. In different browsers under different accounts in the requests I see the same id. If this id is inserted into the request, then a 403 (Forbidden) response and an empty object come

Comment: They changed the api to some extend recently. To circumvent the 403 you would have to send an Header containing a certain key-pair: "Authorization":"OAuth xxxx". You get your OAuth token from your soundcloud cookies after you logged in. This also allows some OAuth functionality to work.

Comment: @SvenGreinert can you elaborate on how to do this? Or alternatively propose an alternative service which provides an API to upload tracks? :)

Comment: @ToivoSäwén Go to SoundCloud.com and log in with your account. In Chrome click on the lock symbol in the URL bar and then on Cookies. Then expand soundcloud.com -> Cookies and copy the content of 'oauth_token'. This is your OAuth token.

Comment: @SvenGreinert yes, that part I managed, but I wasn't sure how to send the header - I kept getting 403 errors even with { "Authorization": "OAuth <token>" } set when sending requests to e.g. api.soundcloud.com/me

Comment: I'm just trying to make a custom player widget for my website (since the default one isn't great and can't be customized). Trying [any of the API endpoints](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/explorer/open-api), even ones that supposedly don't require authentication, I get 401 unauthorized. Looks like I'm stuck with the very limited Widget API.

Comment: Related GitHub issue: https://github.com/soundcloud/api/issues/216

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to create your own audioplayer with soundcloud tracks you can use the widget api: https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget