# How can I get SoundCloud API Access

Tags: soundcloud

Sorry, this is probably not quite stackoverflow question, but I can't see any other way to contact SoundCloud team.
My question is... Do I understand correctly that if I want to use SoundCloud API I need to apply/register new app under my account so I could get user secrets?

I've tried creating a new app under my account but it seems to be switched off.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54753238/soundcloud-application-registration-form-is-closed

Comment: @Lina Va how do you it solved?

Comment: @Sargentogato well, I had to choose a different option.

Comment: @LinaVa thanks... Finally wich options did you choose?

Answer (score 3):

I'm experimenting with the SoundCloud API now, and facing various issues, which is why I came across your post. This is from my experience within the past month.

To get to their API, I did have to register a new app. That's where you end up getting the "Client ID" and "Client Secret" codes.

I sent an email to their support team (support@support.soundcloud.com) telling them that I wanted to register a new app to use their API. I let them know:

- The App Name
- The App Description (briefly)
- How I intended to use their API
- The account I wanted to register the app under.

I received an answer from SoundCloud Support within 48 hours advising the app had been created and the details were under https://soundcloud.com/you/apps.

Hope this helps, and if not you, hopefully it helps someone else in the future!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it looks like the are currently not taking any requests to create new apps (get access to key/credentials for the API)

I reached out to support today and this was the response, quite dissapointing.

```
Unfortunately we're currently not accepting any new developer requests for API keys and don't have an ETA of when it will be open again.
```

If anyone from their team can provide an update that would be great